# How is a Perl filehandle a scalar if it can return multiple lines?

Tags: perl, scalar

I have kind of fundamental question about scalars in Perl. Everything I read says scalars hold one value:

> A scalar may contain one single value in any of three different
>   flavors: a number, a string, or a reference. Although a scalar may not
>   directly hold multiple values, it may contain a reference to an array
>   or hash which in turn contains multiple values.

--from perldoc

Was curious how the code below works

```
open( $IN, "<", "phonebook.txt" )
    or die "Cannot open the file\n";

while ( my $line = <$IN> ) {
    chomp($line);
    my ( $name, $area, $phone ) = split /\|/, $line;
    print "$name $phone $phone\n";
}
close $IN;
```

Just to clarify the code above is opening a pipe delimited text file in the following format `name|areacode|phone`

It opens the file up and then it splits them into `$name $area $phone`; how does it go through the multiple lines of the file and print them out?

Going back to the perldoc quote from above *"A scalar may contain a single value of a string, number, reference."* I am assuming that it has to be a reference, but doesn't even really seem like a reference and if it is looks like it would a reference of a scalar? so I am wondering what is going on internally that allows Perl to iterate through all of the lines in the code?

Nothing urgent, just something I noticed and was curious about. Thanks.

Comment: You're processing the file line by line.  Therefore in each iteration your 3 scalars are assigned new values from the split of the line.  If that's confusing, could you explain more why?

Comment: `<$IN>` is reading from a the file handle. The `< ... >` is an alias for `readline()`. Documentation [here](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/readline.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The old-fashioned way of opening files is to use a bare name for the file handle, like so

```
open IN, 'phonebook.txt'
```

A file handle is a special type of value, like scalar, hash, array etc. but it has no prefix symbol to differentiate it. (This isn't actually the full extent of the truth, but I am worried about confusing you if I add even more detail.)

Perl still works like this, but it is best avoided for a couple of reasons.

- All such file handles are *global*, and there is no way to restrict access to them by scope
- There is no way to pass the value to a subroutine or store it in a data structure

So Perl was enhanced several years ago so that you can use *references* to file handles. These can be stored in scalar variables, arrays, or hashes, and can be passed as subroutine parameters.

What happens now when you write

```
open my $in, '<', 'phonebook.txt'
```

is that perl *autovivifies* an *anonymous* file handle, and puts a reference to it in variable `$in`, so yes, you were right, it *is* a reference. (Another thing that was changed about the same time was the move to three-parameter `open` calls, which allow you to open a file called, say, `>.txt` for input.)

I hope that helps you to understand. It's an unnecessary level of detail, but it can often help you to remember the way Perl works to understand the underlying details.

Incidentally, it is best to keep to lower-case letters for lexical variables, even for file handle references. I often add `fh` to the end to indicate that the variable holds a file handle, like `$in_fh`. But there's no need to use capitals, which are generally reserved for global variables like `Package::Names`.

---

**Update - The Rest of the Story**

I thought I should add something to explain what I have mised out, for fear of misleading people who care about the gory detail.

Perl keeps a symbol table hash - a *stash* - that work very like ordinary Perl hashes. There is one such stash for each package, including the default package `main`. Note that this hash nothing to do with lexical variables - declared with *my* - which are stored entirely separately.

Ther indexes for the stashes are the names of the package variables, without the initial symbol. So, for example, if you have

```
our $val;
our @val;
our %val;
```

then the stash will have only a *single* element, with a key of `val` and a value which is a reference to an intermediate structure called a *typeglob*. This is another hash structure, with one element for each different type of variable that has been declared. In this case our `val` typeglob will have three elements, for the *scalar*, *array*, and *hash* varieties of the `val` variables.

One of these elements may also be an *IO* variable type, which is where file handles are kept. But, for historical reasons, the value that is passed around as a file handle is in fact a reference to the typeglob that contains it. That is why, if you write `open my $in, '<', 'phonebook.txt'` and then `print $in` you will see something like `GLOB(0x269581c)` - the `GLOB` being short for *typeglob*.

Apart from that, the account above is accurate. Perl autovivifies an anonymous *typeglob* in the current package, and uses only its *IO* slot for the file handle.

Comment: Very good thanks!  The gory details is exactly what I was looking for :-).  That does help me understand what is going on.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like Borodin zeroed in on the part you wanted, but I'll add to it.

There are variables, which store things for us, and there are operators, which do things for us. A file handle, the thing you have in `$IN`, isn't the file itself or the data in the file. It's a connection that the program to use to get information from the file.

When you use the line input operator, `<>`, you give it a file handle to tell it where to grab the next line from. By itself, it defaults to `ARGV`, but you can put any file handle in there. In this case, you have `<$IN>`. Borodin already explained the reference and bareword stuff.

So, when you use the line input operator, it look at the connection you give in then gets a line from that file and returns it. You might be able to grok this more easily with it's function form:

```
my $line = readline( $IN );
```

The thing you get back doesn't come out of `$IN`, but the thing it points to. Along the way, `$IN` keeps track of where it is in the file. See `seek` and `tell`.

Along the same lines are Perl's regexes. Many people call something like `/foo.*bar/` a regular expression. They are slightly wrong. There's a regular expression inside the pattern match operator `//`. The pattern is the instructions, but it doesn't do anything by itself until the operator uses it.

I find in my classes if I emphasize the difference between the noun and verb parts of the syntax, people have a much easier time with this sort of stuff.

---

**Old Answer**

Through each iteration of the `while` loop, exactly one value is put into the scalar variables. When the loop is done with a line, everything is reset.

The value in `$line` is a single value: the entire line which you have not broken up yet. Perl doesn't care what that single value looks like. With each iteration, you deal with exactly one line and that's what's in `$line`. Remember, these are variables, which means you can modify and replace their values, so they can only hold one thing *at a time*, but there can be multiple times.

The scalars `$name`, `$area`, and `$phone` have single values, each produced by `split`. Those are lexical variables (`my`), so they are only visible inside the specific loop iteration where they are defined.

Beyond that, I'm not sure which scalar you might be confused about.

Comment: From his question it seems clear that he's confused about the file handle `$IN`. It looks like a scalar value but in his opinion it doesn't behave like one as according to the perldoc quote he supplies.

Comment: @thomascremers summed up my confusion well.  But your response about "Remember, these are variables, which means you can modify and replace their values, so they can only hold one thing at a time, but there can be multiple times" did help with my confusion.  Thank you

Comment: I was confused about a scalar being able to iterate different through the different values.  I was looking for a little bit of the internal working of this process, which was provided by @Borodin.

Comment: Ah, the question has changed significantly since I answered it. It's not even the same question.

Answer (score -2):

Scalars in Perl are denoted by a $ and they can indeed contain the type of values you mention in your questions but next to that they can also contain a file handle. You can create file handles in Perl in two ways one way is Lexical

```
open my $filehandle, '>', '/path/to/file' or die $!;
```

and the other is global

```
open FILEHANDLE, '>', '/path/to/file' or die $!;
```

You should use the Lexical version which is what you're doing.

The `while` loop in your code uses the `<>` operator on your lexical filehandle which returns a line out of your file every time it's called, until it's out of lines (when End Of File is reached) in which case it returns false.

I went into a bit more detail on file handles as it seems it's a concept you're not completely clear on.

Comment: Can those that down vote also please a comment as to what motivated them to do so? What's written here is correct so I'd love to know why this deserved to be down voted